# How to disable and re-enable QPushButton

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I made MainWindow and Dialog with Qt-designer.The MainWindow and Dialog have one QPushButton. Clicking a button in the MainWindow disables the button and opens a Dialog Window. When you click the Dialog button, the Dialog window closes and the MainWindow's button is activated again.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic

form_mainwindow = uic.loadUiType("dialog_mainWindow.ui")[0]
form_dialog = uic.loadUiType("Dialog__.ui")[0]

class dialog(QDialog, form_dialog) :
    def __init__(self):
        super(dialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.closeFN)

    def closeFN(self):
        main = mainwindow()
        main.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

class mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, form_mainwindow) :
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dia)

    def dia(self,checked):
        d = dialog()
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        d.show()
        d.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window = mainwindow()
    Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is my code. However, my code is that when the Dialog window is closed, the button in the MainWindow is not activated again. Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `mainwindow()` in your dialogs `closeFN` method, which creates a new `mainwindow` widget.  So the button that you are setting to be enabled is not the same one that you used to create the dialog in the first place. You are setting a button on a new window that isn't visible yet because you never call `.show()` or similar method that makes top level windows visible, and you also are not keeping a reference to the new window so it would be garbage collected anyway.

A solution to this is to have your `mainwindow` connect to the `dialogs` `closebtn.clicked` signal which could then trigger it's own method that set's the pushbutton to be enabled.

For example:

```py
...

class dialog(QDialog) :
    def __init__(self):
        super(dialog, self).__init__()
        ...
        # self.closeFN is no longer necessary
        self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)

class mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__()
        ...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dia)

    def dia(self):
        d = dialog()
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        # connect to closeBtn signal to enable the pushButton
        d.closeBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pushButton.setEnabled(True))  
        d.exec_()
...
```

Comment: The real problem with the new `main`, is not that it's not shown, but that it will be garbage collected.

Comment: @musicamante  I think creating it in the first place is unintentional, which is why I took it out in my example.

Comment: @Alexander I don't think so, I've seen this kind of attempts very often when trying to switch windows back: they try to do what they think more obvious, which is directly accessing the widget, then they find out that they can't because it creates an AttributeError or NameError, so they try to recreate the window that contains that widget. They normally end up with no-op code like in this case, or a new window that behaves incorrectly. The fact remains, the main technical issue is not that the function creates window, but that it is garbage collected.

Comment: @musicamante  I see your point and agree with you, but even if I had addressed that issue and instructed OP to keep a reference to the window, it wouldn't have solved the OP's problem which was setting the original mainwindow's button to be enabled.

Comment: Yes, I know and agree too, I was only pointing out that that part of the explanation is not completely accurate, since it seems that just adding `show()` would have sufficed to display that new (yet, unwanted) window.

Comment: @musicamante Ohhh...  Okay I can fix that.